# text representation

Tags: java, text, treeview

I have built a family tree program which thus far allows you to add relationships to nodes (mother, father, partner & siblings). This allows the tree to be built. well at least the links to be made.

My problem is I have to represent the tree textually. This is proving to be very hard. I thought of allowing to display the ancestors and descendants for a particular node but this proves to be difficult, especially when there are more than two generations for displaying ancestors (great grandparents and above).

To make things more clear I thought of using a file tree structure but got into a mess when displaying for great grandparents.

I can provide the source if anyone wants to see it.

---

What I mean is using a file structure starts of with a pair of people: 
e.g.

GRANDAD & GRANDMA 
---DAD
 
------ME 
------SISTER 
---AUNT
 
------COUSIN 
------COUSIN

This would be for showing my ancestors on my dads side (inclusive of me). My question is what happens if both my grandparents have parents? How would I represent such relationships with the above structure? I would have to show my great grand-parents but there would be two sets! One for my grandma and one for my grandad. The root has been split into two if you see what I mean....

I though about limiting the 'show ancestors' function to show only 2 generations above. Which means that a user can traverse through the tree and indentify his/her great grandparents by selecting their parent nodes and displaying their ancestors - but this seems laborious and not very intuitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following method may do what you want.  It will print a tree in a tabbed hierarchical structure:

```
public void printTree(Node root, int tabLevel, PrintStream out){
    for(int i =0;i < tabLevel; i++) out.print("\t");
    out.println(root)
    for(Node n: root.getChildren())
        printTree(n, tabLevel + 1, out);
}
```

You would call it like so:

```
printTree(rootNode, 0, System.out);
```

This doesn't take into account all of the the complexities of a family tree, but it should provide a good place to start.

Comment: maybe i should have replied to you i stead of a swering my own question. oops! what I'm saying is I guess logically I'm confused on how to display great grandparents for a particular node.

Comment: @user, One node will not have great grandparents by itself.  One node will only have parents and children.  So, to show a node's great grandparents, you have to display that node's parents.  And then the parent's parents, and then their parent's parents. Does that make sense?